# Cannot set EditText's style

Tags: android

I created my own style for EditText, but it doesn't work

Style:

```
<style name="InputTextBox" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="background">@drawable/text_area_box</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">top</item>
    </style>
```

EditText in XML:

```
 <EditText
        app:theme="@style/InputTextBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_to"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner_from"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/spinner_to"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:hint="@string/translate_text_input_hint"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:id="@+id/et_input_text" />
```

I tried to change parent in styles to Widget.AppCompat.EditText, Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText and others but still have no result

Comment: Try style="@style/InputTextBox

Comment: @VVB it helped, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For setting style on `EditText` you need to set `android:theme`.

```
 <EditText
       android:theme="@style/InputTextBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_to"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner_from"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/spinner_to"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:hint="@string/translate_text_input_hint"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:id="@+id/et_input_text" />
```